# RHEL sudo still not allowed for user 'tina'

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I'd like 2 users, 'tina' and 'lu' to execute a few utils like /bin/chmod. Here's the relevant portion of my `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
tina,lu ALL=/bin/chmod /bin/chown /bin/chgrp
```

Then I logged in as myself, and then logged in as tina using

```
su - tina
```

Then I tried to get the tina username to do chmod on a file. tina's permissions don't seem to be working. Here's the output of `sudo -l -U tina`

```
Matching Defaults entries for tina on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC
    KDEDIR LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE
    LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER
    LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Runas and Command-specific defaults for tina:


User tina may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) /bin/chmod /bin/chown /bin/chgrp
```

And when I actually try to do a chmod logged in as her. `copyf` is a new shell script I'm working on.

```
tina 118->chmod 770 copyf
chmod: changing permissions of `copyf': Operation not permitted
tina 119->sudo chmod 770 copyf
Sorry, user tina is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod 770 copyf' as root on xpp.
```

Did I forget to set something up?

Comment: You're aware that the combination of `chmod` and `chown` has given away the keys to the castle? Tina can create a file, change its ownership to root, and then fix the permissions so it's setuid root. Bingo.

Answer (score 9):

You are missing the commas:

```
tina,lu ALL = /bin/chmod, /bin/chown, /bin/chgrp
```

Without the commas you are giving the right to execute

```
/bin/chmod /bin/chown /bin/chgrp
```

which of course doesn't make sense, but is syntactically valid as far as `visudo` knows.